# Можно ли скачать несколько видео в одном M3U8 плейлисте?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

Есть ли способ скачать несколько видео в одном M3U8 плейлисте с помощью FFmpeg? К примеру у меня есть сериал, который выглядит так:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF: 0,1x1 (Ход королевы)
#EXTVLCOPT:http-user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; Mobile/QP1A.190711.020; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/87.0.4280.101 Mobile Safari/537.36
http://grendel.stream.voidboost.cc/1/4/0/6/7/8/787bf7475baf39563c4337d69e99111d:2020123021/zp179.mp4:hls:manifest.m3u8
#EXTINF: 0,1x2 (Ход королевы)
#EXTVLCOPT:http-user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; Mobile/QP1A.190711.020; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/87.0.4280.101 Mobile Safari/537.36
http://minos.stream.voidboost.cc/9/5/9/9/5/ab6f5bc984d2b181270ef40f6a0b26f7:2020123021/kirom.mp4:hls:manifest.m3u8
```

Comment: Chrome открывает эти ссылки, т.е. можно просто `curl` натравить (и, если честно, не понимаю каким боком здесь `ffmpeg`... хотите сразу на экран?).

Comment: @0andriy по ссылке получается ещё пара m3u плейлистов, а ffmpeg нужен для склейки hls (ts) сегментов в один контейнер mp4

Answer (score 1):

Можно скачать полный файл стерев последние символы:

```
http://minos.stream.voidboost.cc/<path>/kirom.mp4
```

Например:

```
https://terbium.stream.voidboost.in/tvseries/<path>/1080.mp4:hls:seg-1-v1-a1.ts
```

стираем: `:hls:seg-1-v1-a1.ts` и получаем полный файл. Далее просто сохраняем его.

Answer (score 0):

Открываем терминал (консоль) и вводим туда такую команду:

> ffmpeg -y -loglevel verbose -i $urlvideo -c copy -f mpegts video.mp4

— где, вместо $urlvideo — подставляем из буфера обмена ссылку, $urlvideo лучше вводить в кавычках!

https://vk.com/@rosa_kali-kak-skachat-potokovoe-video-s-saita-m3u8-v-tch-dostupnoe-tol